# Why nodejs error? It's Error 583. How do I fix the fever?

Tags: node.js

It's an error. Follow the usual method. I want to know how to fix I tried to delete it again and still not missing this error.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\work\test.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)

Comment: Spltting a question between post, comment and answer? I can't remember the last time I witnessed that much raw power.

Comment: I didn't use it, so I forgot how to use the website, but put an error below.

Comment: Error says module `mysql` cannot be found, have you tried to install it?

Comment: i installed , But probably caused an error

Comment: try `npm install mysql --save`. Also can you put the "answer" you wrote in the question?

Comment: I does ,not good

Answer (score 0):

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\work\test.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```